# How can i schedule different tasks for different days in a week in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I want my app to do different calculation according to the day in a week.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling) (or its compat versions like FirebaseJobDiscpatcher/Evernote AndroidJob).
[Here](https://android.jlelse.eu/schedule-tasks-and-jobs-intelligently-in-android-e0b0d9201777?gi=4e8220ac3ee6) is another article on scheduling tasks.

Just make job period ~24hr and check date with Calendar or other Date tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to accomplish this.

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
mDate = mSimpleDateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

int time = Integer.parseInt(mDate);
        int dayOfWeek = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int dayOfMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int weekOfYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                doSomething();
}

public void doSomething() {
//do something here
}
```

You can look at this project to help you better https://github.com/mbobiosio/DateTime/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/talentbox/mbobiosio/datetime/MainActivity.java